# Flask Admin extend "with select"-dropdown menu with custom button

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Im using the built-in view of flask admin. As you can see in the picture below: [image]

What Im trying is simple: I just want to extend the dropdown menu with a custom button. This button should perfome some action on all selected items. 
Is there are built-in function of flask where i can simple add an action button?

Comment: Im also open for other ways. Im still struggling. I have tried to modifiy the base.py file and the corresponding template but It seems really complicated and I coudln´t find a similar problem on the internet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`@action`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_actions/) decorator. Simple example below, the text "Recalculate Charges" is what appears in the drop-down menu.

```py
class TransactionView(AdminView):
    
    from flask_admin.actions import action

    @action('recalculate', 'Recalculate Charges', 'Are you sure you want to recalculate selected transactions(s)?')
    def action_recalculate(self, ids):
        count = 0
        for _id in ids:
            # Do some work with the id, e.g. call a service method
            transaction_service.recalculate_transaction(_id)
            count += 1
        flash("{0} transaction (s) charges recalculated".format(count))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.  Now Im able to iterate through the selected items and do what I want. You saved my day.

Comment: For someone new to or learning flask-admin this answer isn't easily digestible.  References to models and importing necessary functions isn't clear. Just throwing that out there. Appreciate the answer though.

Comment: Well I'm new to flask but I thought this example was everything I needed. Although added the import would have been nice: `from flask_admin.actions import action`